Why my MLX90614ESF-DCI sensor saturates at 300°C?
I have an MLX90614ESF-DCI FIR sensor to measure a metal rod temperature. Everything is fine below 300°C. But exactly at 300°, the measured temperature is saturated and doesn't show higher values. I expect to measure up to 380°C based on the information provided on the datasheet of the sensor.
Edit:
Here is the schematic of my circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
and the code for reading the sensor value is something like following:
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

int status = 0;
void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);
    if(!mlx.begin())
        status = 1;
}

void loop(){

    Serial.println(mlx.readObjectTempC());
    delay(5);
}

As I mentioned I have no issue reading the value of temperature from this sensor. The main problem is that the sensor saturates for temperatures values above 300 °C while regarding the info on datasheet I supposed to measured values up to 380 °C.

To help get an answer can you edit the question to include (a) A schematic of how the MLX90614ESF-DCI sensor is connected to the arduino (b) The code used to read the measured temperature (c) If the temperature measurement is read using the PWM output or SMBus interface of the MLX90614ESF-DCI.

Are you using the latest version of the library (appears to be 2023-11-15)?

@SpehroPefhany I doubt that this issue relates to the version. The version 2.1.5 is installed. I also checked the raw value read from the sensor. this raw value is also saturated at this point. It is like a limit on the sensor firmware or can it be fake sensor? I really have no Idea what I need to check now!

How do you make sure that the rod is in fact in excess of 300C? Have you taken into account the emissivity of the surface you're measuring?

Are you using a module with the 3.3V regulator and I2C pullup resistors on-board, or the bare sensor?

@SpehroPefhany I am using the module with regulator and level shifter on it.

@MrGerber I heated a heater and measured the temperature using a hand held IR tempreture sensor. The tempreture goes up to 390 but my sensor value stocks exactly on 300 each time i did this test.

@SpehroPefhany I also emailed the melexis for this issue but I didn't receive any response up to now. I couldn't find any link for the company that made this module! Do you know if  CJMCU is a specific company that makes this module?

You didn’t link the supplier or disclose where you got it, but I suspect there are many small suppliers assembling those few parts. It’s possible the Melexis part is something slightly different, made for the China market or whatever. It’s suspicious that the calibration of their arrays stops at 300’C.

What value does mlx.readEmissivity() return? The MLX90614 has an EEPROM register which can stores the emissivity correction and if a non-default value has been set that could modify the returned object temperature.

What is the metal rod for which the temperature is being measured? Emissivity - Metals shows how the Emissivity can vary for different metals, which might need to be taken into account in converting a measurement to object temperature.

@ChesterGillon It is default value 1.0. I also changed it and it didn't help.I was checking for any info for this sensor and I find out DFROBOT sells this sensor and in the description they claim the max sensor read value is 270 °c but in datasheet I couldn't find any information about this!
